# Parameters of a function

Tags: glsl, webgl

So i've been following this online tutorial on webgl and i've gotten to this part where "gl_FragColor = vec4(surfacePosition, 0., 1.)*cos(time); " is used . And i've been searching everywhere to find what that 0. and 1. stand for. So what i'm asking if anyone could explain what these parameters are? And why exactly do i have to provide the position of the pixel (surfacePosition) to a color function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vec4 constructor need a 4 dimension value (which is to say 4 values).

(basically RGBA as it's for a color)

So as you give it a 2 dimension value with `surfacePosition` (which will be red and green component), 2 values are still needed, which will represent the blue component and the transparency component, which are respectively 0. and 1.

(0 and 1 casted to floating point numbers)

That's it for the first question.

For the second one it simply depends on what you want to do.
Using the position of the pixel (in case `surfacePosition` actually represent it) directly as components in the resulting color suggest that you just want to color pixels depending on their position.

But it just depends on what's your goal, you don't "have to provide the position of the pixel", you just compute the final color as you want.

Comment: thanks a lot very clear answer can i bother you with one more question , is there a site or a pdf anything where i could find explanations for all those glsl functions or webgl related stuff?

Comment: Well I don't really see anything, I always have a quickcard ref and just browse SO when I encounter a serious problem, can't really help you on that

Comment: @Patratel glsl related stuff -> https://www.khronos.org/files/webgl/webgl-reference-card-1_0.pdf and webgl related stuff -> https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/